# bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay and cacheDisplay on cloned view show incorrect pixels

Tags: macos, appkit

I have 2 NSView heirarchies, one comes from my window, which is currently on screen. The other has been created using this code on the origianl view:

var newView = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: originalView))!

---

I generate 2 pairs of files in my test code, one file is all the pixels from the view hierarchy and the other file is the top 128 pixels of the view hierarchy. The full file looks correct regardless of which view hierarchy I start with. The file with the top 128 pixels is the right size for the cloned views, but has all transparent pixels in it.

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var outerView: NSTextView!

var innerView: NSTextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var innerFrame = outerView!.frame
    innerFrame.origin.x = 20.0
    innerFrame.origin.y = 20.0
    innerFrame.size.width -= 30.0
    innerFrame.size.height = 2048.0

    innerView = NSTextView(frame: innerFrame)
    innerView!.allowsUndo = true
    outerView!.autoresizesSubviews = false
    outerView!.addSubview(innerView!)

    innerView.textStorage?.beginEditing()
    innerView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString())
    innerView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string:
        "Inner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text\nInner View Text"
    ))
    innerView.textStorage?.endEditing()

}

@IBAction func createDemoFiles(_ sender: Any) {

    //  create file with views from window

    var aFrame = outerView.frame
    aFrame.size.height = innerView.frame.size.height
    outerView.frame = aFrame

    //  dump full image

    var dumpFrame = aFrame

    var bitmap: NSBitmapImageRep? = outerView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: dumpFrame)
    outerView.cacheDisplay(in: dumpFrame, to: bitmap!)
    var filePath = "/Users/gdragon/Downloads/windowViewsFullFrame.tiff"
    var someDtaa: NSData = bitmap!.tiffRepresentation! as NSData
    someDtaa.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

    //  dump partial image

    dumpFrame.origin.y = dumpFrame.size.height - 128
    dumpFrame.size.height = 128

    bitmap = outerView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: dumpFrame)
    outerView.cacheDisplay(in: dumpFrame, to: bitmap!)
    filePath = "/Users/gdragon/Downloads/windowViews128Frame.tiff"
    someDtaa = bitmap!.tiffRepresentation! as NSData
    someDtaa.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

    //  create file with views from cloned view

    let clonedView = outerView.cloneView() as! NSTextView
    aFrame = clonedView.frame
    aFrame.size.height = innerView.frame.size.height
    clonedView.frame = aFrame

    //  dump full image

    dumpFrame = aFrame

    bitmap = clonedView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: dumpFrame)
    clonedView.cacheDisplay(in: dumpFrame, to: bitmap!)
    filePath = "/Users/gdragon/Downloads/clonedViewsFullFrame.tiff"
    someDtaa = bitmap!.tiffRepresentation! as NSData
    someDtaa.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

    //  dump partial image

    dumpFrame.origin.y = dumpFrame.size.height - 128
    dumpFrame.size.height = 128

    bitmap = clonedView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: dumpFrame)
    clonedView.cacheDisplay(in: dumpFrame, to: bitmap!)
    filePath = "/Users/gdragon/Downloads/clonedViews128Frame.tiff"
    someDtaa = bitmap!.tiffRepresentation! as NSData
    someDtaa.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

}
```

}

When I run my test code on the views in the window it works correctly. When I run my test code on the cloned view, the smaller file is empty.

The tiff/write code is not causing the error, the code above comes from a project where I use this technique to create OpenGL textures from an NSView hierarchy and when I examine the contents of the bitmap data, the pixels are all 0,0,0,0.

I've checked the frames/bounds of both sets of views and they are the same. 
I am clearly not setting something up correctly, but so far I can't figure out what I missed.